# Binding multiple items to clipboard?

Tags: macos, system-settings

Is it possible to bind more than one items to the clipboard on osx? Which would possibly get evoked by different shortcuts?
If it is how can I set it up?

I simply need to have a string always available at my disposal, but would like to keep my clipboard free for other uses.

Comment: You need a thirty part application like [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com), [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com)... and much more.

Comment: A free tool is ClipMenu www.clipmenu.com

Comment: Just for fun, there's a ClipboardViewer program available as source code in the Mac Developer Library: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I recommend this 3rd party tool: http://pasteapp.me/ . Much better than the free ones and better than the more expensive ones I've seen too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a second clipboard in OS X, called the kill-ring. Press <kbd>Control ^</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to "kill" (cut) the rest of the current line to the kill-ring, and <kbd>Control ^</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to "yank" (paste) it.

Comment: Brilliant, that is just what I was looking for... easy and inbuilt.

Answer (score 2):

For one simple string, or as many as you like - why not use the built-in text replacer - System Prefs > Keyboard > Text.

As many as you like, as complex as you like, simple memorable triggers.

And, what's more… it's free ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the best third-party apps is the excellent CopyPaste Pro http://plumamazing.com/mac/copypaste